# Activities names are unresolvable after changing the project directory and module name

Tags: java, android-studio, android-manifest

Earlier the project was working fine but when I changed the project directory and module name,then error began. 
Now, when I add a new activity with its xml the new file is in red color.
I have tried writing the full path name, but there is no change

> I think there is some path issue while changing the Project name.

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.parse.starter.twitter">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:name=".StarterApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Twitter"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".FeedActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".UsersActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="Twitter">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[image: description]

MainActivity xml file

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: description]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem several times.
You may clean and rebuild project in Build toolbar. Or you may use Invalidate Caches/Restart in File toolbar. Both of them may solve your problem.